# Process image in multi threads using BufferedImage java

Tags: java, multithreading, image-processing, bufferedimage

Hello i've got a question for you. I know java a little bit and i need your help.
I am trying to process image by multi threading. The idea is simple. I load pixel by pixel in threads, then store it in bufferedImage object, then save. I am going to use fixed nubmer of threads.

This is my way to achieve it. I am posting links due to long code

http://pastebin.com/zuD9JTxn
http://pastebin.com/FBZzsG2i

Now every thread after calculating new rgb value for particular pixel, sends it to App.
I wish i could store it in array, then send it all to app, then merge with other threads.
Is this possible?

Comment: You should probably include the *relevant* code your question, and use English method names to get better help. :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are some image processing frameworks that provide features to do so. For example, in the case of [Marvin](http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net), you can create masks containing specific regions of a given image. Then, you create threads to process each region idependently.

[image]

In the case above, the single thread approach processed a 873x601 image in 650ms. A multithreaded approach (2 threads) processed in 370ms.

**Below is presented the part of the source coce responsible to deal with multithreading:**

```
    // Create two masks
    MarvinImageMask mask1 = new MarvinImageMask
    (
        imageIn.getWidth(),         // width
        imageIn.getHeight(),        // height
        0,                          // x-start
        0,                          // y-start
        imageIn.getWidth(),         // region´s width
        imageIn.getHeight()/2       // region´s height
    );

    MarvinImageMask mask2 = new MarvinImageMask
    (
        imageIn.getWidth(),         // width
        imageIn.getHeight(),        // height
        0,                          // x-start
        imageIn.getHeight()/2,      // y-start
        imageIn.getWidth(),         // region´s width
        imageIn.getHeight()/2       // region´s height
    );

    // Create two threads to process the same image (imageIn) using the algorithm l_pluginImage_1 and l_pluginImage_2
    MarvinThread marvinThread_1 = new MarvinThread(pluginImage_1, imageIn, imageOut, mask1);
    MarvinThread marvinThread_2 = new MarvinThread(pluginImage_2, imageIn, imageOut, mask2);

    marvinThread_1.start();
    marvinThread_2.start();
```

The complete source code you can check [HERE](http://sourceforge.net/p/marvinproject/code/HEAD/tree/dev/trunk/MarvinSamples/src/image/multithread/Multithread.java).

Answer (score 0):

The [Fork/Join](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) framework of Java7 can be usefull in this application.

Answer (score 0):

A `BufferedImage` is basically a wrapper around an array (of some sort). From my understanding after briefly looking at your code, you are just changing the color of the pixels, based on the original color of the pixel. No computation is based on previous computations.

This means that you can just let any number of threads work on their part of the image and write the value right back to the image. When the threads are all done, you have an updated image.

And yes, use Fork/Join and the `java.util.concurrent` package in general.